# Code assist - Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, webstorm

I am following this tutorial http://vimeo.com/album/1573372/video/37212149

It seems that there is a way to type "xmodel" and have a standard model's code generated automatically. I am using Webstorm IDE - is there a way of doing this in it, and any configurations I can import?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems 'Live Templates' is the feature you refer to - it allows expanding abbreviations into code snippets. See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/live-templates.html, http://davidtucker.net/articles/live-templates-phpstorm-webstorm/

WebStorm doesn't come with predefined live templates for Sencha, but you can easily create them yourself or search the web for existing templates. See [ST2 Power Tools](https://github.com/davidtucker/ST2PowerTools), for example